# How to create custom MKMarkerAnnotationView image?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I want to create a marker on a mapView with a custom image. Is it possible to display images and titles simultaneously? I've tried several approaches

- MKMarkerAnnotation view. With .image it sets the image, but the default bubble still stands, with .glyphImage I can't get the image to retain the original color
- MKPinAnnotation. I get no title displayed.

I need both of them to be displayed at the same time as MKMarkerAnnotationView, but with a custom pin image. What can I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works with custom class mkAnnotation, i'm not sure is it best practice or not, but it works in my app. 
try something like this...

```
class SightMap: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
     let identifier = "pinImage"
     //+ something else, for example 
     var image: UIImage?
}
///somewhere in your code
     let sightmap = SightMap(...init...)
     map?.addAnnotation(sightmap)

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pinImage")
        view.addSubview(YOUR_IMAGE)
        view.addSubview(YOUR_label)

    }
```